# Long and strange URI string in .m3u8 file

Tags: uri, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I encountered such a strange .m3u8 file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:16
#EXT-X-KEY:MEATHOD=AES-128,URI="NTdiMThhZWEtMmQ0OS00YmNmLThhYzktMjUwOWYwYzRhN2U1QnpKd200eXVuU0toK1Q3RzRLSUsyUzJDVWdReHNtZTFBQUFBQUFBQUFBRHBsc2J1Sk9MWFZhejk2U2FnbFFrM3dIQlhBek1OZWxZcFdIZWU1NCtnaFM1SmVpL1RCNTk1"
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:15.120000,
...
...
```

I expect the URI to be a link to the key.key file, but as it's shown above, the URI is a 176-character long string. I guess the original link is encrypted somehow. Does someone know this method and decode the .ts files?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100%, but fairly certain this is [Alibaba Cloud proprietary cryptography](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/apsaravideo-for-vod/latest/alibaba-cloud-proprietary-cryptography#concept-1997170).

Since the documentation states it can only be played back using the Alibaba player, and `MEATHOD` is deliberately mispelt, I suspect that that player knows how to make a request to some licence service to retrieve the relevant key for playback, using the data in the `URI` field.

If you take the URI and base64 decode it you get a UUID (possibly a key ID?) followed by a bunch of other binary data. Comparing yours with other examples available publicly, it seems to follow the same structure for each piece of media.

Also worth noting that the segments themselves are not encrypted, only their payload.

In short, it seems unlikely you will be able to decrypt this yourself.